# How can I force Firefox to select the tab to the right on tab close?

Tags: firefox

I'm using TMP 0.3.8.2 and a host of other extensions on FF 3.6.3 on OSX 10.6. I've tried disabling all other extensions that might interfere with tab settings but it's hard to keep track of everything because I have literally 60 (about 30 are disabled though) that are on and off in various configurations. I'm wondering if there's a way to FORCE Firefox to select the tab to the right on closing a tab, in such a way that it overrides any other setting anywhere else. I realize the prospects for this are dim. Thanks.

Comment: If there is some universal solution, I'd suspect it to be in about:config, but I'm not seeing anything that looks related there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tab Mix Plus Options**, Events, Tab Closing, Closing current tab, Opener/right tab, Okay.
Maybe you have already tried that... If so, does it remain saved across firefox restarts?
If settings are not saved across FF restart, look at -- [Preferences are not saved](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Preferences+are+not+saved).

Comment: I have it set just to right, because I don't want opener, but yes, I do have it set to that, and it does report that that is the preference across sessions, and yet that is not the behavior. I even tried changing the preference and then setting it back to right-only to see if that might jolt it back into proper behavior, but to no avail.

Comment: Since I now use Chrome I'm just going to accept this answer...